# Javascript casting

Tags: javascript, web

I have this array

```
var myArr = [];
myArr[0] = 'hello world';
myArr[1] = 'hello universe';
```

Then i want to convert myArr[1] element to upper case how should i do this?

I could use

```
document.write( myArr[1].toUpperCase() );
```

or should I use

```
document.write( String( myArr[1] ).toUpperCase() );
```

what is better in terms of performance?

Comment: what purpose does doing `String(myArr[1])` serve?

Comment: of course document.write( myArr[1].toUpperCase() ); is batter then other because myarray already in string so don't need to convert in string

Answer (score 2):

myArr[1] is already a string, so I don't think you need to cast it again, so

```
document.write( myArr[1].toUpperCase() );
```

is the right thing to do

Answer (score 2):

Performance doesn't matter here

There is almost never a reason to call the String() constructor. What you have is already a string